# File does not exist error while trying to read from Sharepoint

Tags: python, sharepoint, office365, ms-office

I'm trying to read a file in a sharepoint site using Office365-REST-Python-Client. The code I'm running is below.

```
from office365.runtime.auth.user_credential import UserCredential
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.sharepoint.files.file import File
site_url = "https://mycompany.sharepoint.com"
relative_url = "/sites/mysite/Shared%20Documents/sampledata.xlsx"
ctx = ClientContext(site_url).with_credentials(UserCredential("username", "password"))
response = File.open_binary(ctx, relative_url)
```

However, on printing out `response.text` it is giving me the error:
`{"error":{"code":"-2130575338, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The file /sites/mysite/Shared Documents/sampledata.xlsx does not exist."}}}`

The username and password I have provided does work and I was able to verify that with my code as well, so it is not something related to login. Could someone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your site_url to
site_url = "https://mycompany.sharepoint.com/sites/{your_site_name_}/"

Comment: Hello, please add some more details to your answers here, e.g. why you think this is the optimal solution for the problem.